# Fiddler no capture on startup

Tags: fiddler

How can i make fiddler not automatically start capturing traffic on startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 49):

Use the command line argument:

`fiddler.exe -noattach`

or, click Tools > Options… > Connections and untick "Act as system proxy on startup" if you never want Fiddler to start attached.

Answer (score 5):

Go here:

```
v4.6.1.5:  Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections
```

Untick "Act As System Proxy on Startup"

You can always use F12 to toggle on as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a syntax update for the command line option at some point or else it has to do with the OS. For Windows 10 x64:

**Use:**

```
Fiddler.exe /noattach
```

**Don't use:**

```
Fiddler.exe -noattach
```

**Ref:**

http://fiddler.wikidot.com/commandlineparams

Comment: Using the OS you mentioned, "-" still works for me. The link you gave actually states "/" is the old way and "-" is the new one. You can run Fiddler.exe -? and you'll see they ask to use "-".